# How can I disable spellcapcheck for the first line of a FileType?

Tags: spell-checking

I've added the following to my `~/.vimrc`:

```
autocmd FileType gitcommit setlocal spell
```

This is great, as when I'm editing a got commit message, I now have `spell` enabled.

However, our commit style guidelines state that the commit message (the first line, a subject line) should always be lowercase, triggering spell's detection.

Is there a way to express that `spellcapcheck` should disable for only the first line fo that scope?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by changing the filetype syntax using [`:syn-spell`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/syntax.txt.html#%3asyn%2dspell):

```
:sy[ntax] spell [toplevel | notoplevel | default]
    This defines where spell checking is to be done for text that is not
    in a syntax item:

    toplevel:   Text is spell checked.
    notoplevel: Text is not spell checked.
    default:    When there is a @Spell cluster no spell checking.

    For text in syntax items use the @Spell and @NoSpell clusters
    |spell-syntax|.  When there is no @Spell and no @NoSpell cluster then
    spell checking is done for "default" and "toplevel".
```

You can see `$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/tex.vim` as an example, similar to what was done [this question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/8091/1405).

But it not possible to control only the capitalization. You'll need to disable the entire spell check on the first word of the file.